# Chart.js HiLo chart example

Tags: chart.js

With [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/), is it possible to create [a HiLo chart like this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/ARNET3/ar3conHiLoCharts.html%20?)?

Optionally with custom points like arrows.

Comment: Stacked charts?  [Samples](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/)

Comment: It won't work since we need single bar with two Y coordinates per item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use floating bars for this:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [
        [2, 3],
        [1, 6],
        [4, 8],
        [6, 9],
        [1, 5],
        [0, 3]
      ],
      backgroundColor: 'orange'
    }, ]
  },
  options: {}
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.0/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```