# How to Create Chart.JS Bar Graph with Min, Max & Average

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I have an app that is generating some bart charts from a service. My client added an additional chart to display a range (min, max and average). I was wondering if their is a way to accomplish this using chart.js. I looked through their docs and wasn't able to find any examples or documentation on how to accomplish this. Anyone else run into this or have a different library they prefer?
[image: A Graph That Looks Something Like This]

Comment: Can you draw something or show a sample of what you are looking for?

Comment: @Teddy I just added image to original post

Comment: Maybe it's not supported.. I'm not sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46526949/chart-js-hilo-chart-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine "floating bars" and "stacked bar chart". See https://codepen.io/fantasyzer/pen/KKaqgoM for an example. Note that the `data` of each bar is given as an array [Ybegin,Yend]. If you set `stackable` to `false` for the y scale the values are to be given as absolute:

```
  datasets: [
  {
    data: [
      [10,12],
      [20,25],
      [15,25],
      [25,28],
  ...
```

[image: Floating stacked bar chart example on codepen.io]

Ref:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/floating.html, https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html

Comment: Hi Pete, i see u code, but no work with this configuration. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66908235/chartjs-bar-min-max-and-avarage-value Can u help me?

Comment: Everything changed since I wrote this answer so I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I completely failed to get this working for bar charts (works for line, scatter, radar).   Then I found new chartjs 2.9 feature here [Min Max bar values](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5262)

Using this on bar and horizontalBar successfully.

Comment: Feel free to reference [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It is often more helpful if you include at least a brief explanation along with your [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)