# Chartjs bar min, max and avarage value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Hi I have a chart with chartjs, which inserts between min, max, average values, with a bar type chart.
So far, everything is fine, the values are entered, what I want to do is that the bars of the graph are positioned starting from their min on the y axis up to the maximum on the y axis, I do not want the bar to start from the value 0.

```
dataset = {
  labels: ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday'],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'min',
      borderWidth: 4,
      borderColor: "#ef4931",
      backgroundColor: "#ef4931",
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: data[1],
      fill: false,
    },
    {
      label: 'avg',
      borderWidth: 4,
      borderColor: "#ef4931",
      backgroundColor: "#ef4931",
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: data[0],
      fill: "-1",
    },
    {
      label: 'max',
      borderWidth: 4,
      borderColor: "#ef4931",
      backgroundColor: "#ef4931",
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      data: data[2],
      fill: "-1",
    }
  ]
};

options = {
  legend: {
    display: false,
  },
  title: {
    display: true,
    position: 'bottom',
    fontSize: 14
  },
  tooltips: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
    titleFontStyle: "bold",
    titleFontColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
    bodyFontStyle: "normal",
    bodyFontColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)",
    borderWidth: 1,
    bodySpacing: 5,
    xPadding: 15,
    yPadding: 15,
    displayColors: false,
    callbacks: {
      title: function(item, data) {
        var title = "";
        title += item[0].xLabel;
        return title;
      }
    }
  },
  responsive: true,
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      barThickness: 10,
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true,
      display: true,
      scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        fontSize: 14,
        fontStyle: "bold",
      },
      ticks: {
        callback: function(value, index, values) {
          return parseInt(value) + " bpm";
        },
      }
    }]
  },
  animation: {
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeInOutQuad"
  }
};

myChart.config.data = dataset;
myChart.options = options;
myChart.config.type = "bar";
myChart.update();
```

Answer (score 0):

in your y axes config you can add the prop `suggestedMin` or `min` between the `stacked` and `display` prop. With this the scale will start at that number, here you can put in the value of the lowest bar.

SuggestedMin will go lower if there is a bar with a lower value, if you use min if will use that as a final so if you have a bar with a lower value it wont get shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine "floating bars" and "stacked bar chart". See https://codepen.io/fantasyzer/pen/KKaqgoM for an example. Note that the `data` of each bar is given as an array [Ybegin,Yend]. If you set `stackable` to `false` for the y scale the values are to be given as absolute:

```
  datasets: [
  {
    data: [
      [10,12],
      [20,25],
      [15,25],
      [25,28],
  ...
```

[image: Floating stacked bar chart example on codepen.io]

Ref:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/floating.html, https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/stacked.html